# VARCHAR in parameter of IN clause in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have this string in PHP:

```
$temp = 'one, two, three, four, five, six';
```

I call the SQL server Stored Procedure in this way:

```
$tsql_callSP = "{call spThisIsCalled($temp)}";
```

I have the following as the Stored Procedure in SQL server and there is soome problem, I don't know what:

```
CREATE PROC spThisIsCalled(
    @serverVar VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Something, @serverVar
    FROM (  .............
            WHERE
                (........ IN
                ([@serverVar]))
                AS PVT;
END
```

The @serverVar in the Stored Procedure are the column names but somehow it is not working due to some problem. Please help.

Comment: Does `@ServerVar` is set when you call the Stored Procedure from PHP?

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro-substitution.  You would need use some DYNAMIC SQL for this

Comment: You cannot use a variable to specify a column name. You need to build dynamic SQL if you want to specify a column name as an argument.

Comment: None of the hundreds of questions like this on this site helped you?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, I was not able to find the exact answer that I wanted and that could help. Thanks for the participation tho. :)

Comment: @henriqueromao Yes, it is set already.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it is not possible. you can try to move all your code to a variable and then execute, some thing like

```
CREATE PROC spThisIsCalled(
    @serverVar VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @sqlCommand varchar(max) = 
'SELECT Something, ' + @serverVar +  ' FROM (  .............
            WHERE
                (........ IN
                (' +  @serverVar + ' ]))AS PVT; ' ;

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sqlCommand
End
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not sure why did you include those 'N' in front of SELECT and after @serverVar. Please help with that.

Comment: You do not need use 'N' because you are using a varchar data type. I edited the code.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate. :)